# Return response not downloading through pandas Django

Tags: python, django

I want to export the query data if the form is valid after submitting two dates from a modal form. I don't understand why the return response is not working here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def load_date_range_ajax(request):
  data = dict()
  template_name ='date_range_modal.html'

  if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
      form = DateRangeForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          data['form_is_valid'] = True
          start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
          end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        
          with connection.cursor() as cursor:
              cursor.execute('''qry_string;''')
              rows = cursor.fetchall()

          response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
          response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Location Date.xlsx"'
          df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description])
          df.to_excel(response, index=False, header=True)
        
        
          return response
      else:
          data['form_is_valid'] = False
  else:
      form = DateRangeForm()
    
  data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context={'form': form}, request=request)
  return JsonResponse(data)
```